# How do I copy text from vim on a remote host in Terminal, to local MacOS clipboard?

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, vim, copy-paste

I've googled the heck out of this but nothing I try solves the problem.  Help?

### Context

I'm running vim on a remote linux machine, which I ssh to in Terminal.app.
I have root on the remote machine, so I can install any vim I want.
I've tried installing vim-gtk, and comfirmed that vi --version includes +clipboard and +xterm_clipboard
I don't use gnome so that's a nonstarter.

### Symptoms

When I try to use `"*5yy` then vim reports that it yanked 5 lines, but they do not appear in my MacOS system clipboard.

### Help!

Answers such as [How can I copy into the Mac clipboard from vim?](https://superuser.com/questions/690436/how-can-i-c) all assume I'm running vim on my MacOS machine.
I know this is a frequent question but nobody seems to be doing exactly what I'm doing.  Does anyone have this setup and know how to get it working?
Thanks for any help!
In the meantime, as a workaround, I'll just use pico, which for some reason easily does what I want with no issues.  In fact it's better;  I can just select and then copy/paste.
But I'd like to know how to solve this for vim if possible as I cannot rely on pico to exist everywhere or at all runlevels.
Cheers

Comment: btw, it's kill to 'cut', yank to 'paste'.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm on MacOS.  I want to copy and paste.  kill and yank are only internal to vim and do not seem to be compatible somehow

Comment: "it yanked 5 lines" - it wouldn't appear on your clipboard, because it should be yanking *from* the clipboard. Kill & yank work just fine on Mac btw, Ctrl/K & Ctrl/Y. The clipboard is not shared with copy/paste & works quite a bit differently.

Comment: That's exactly my point.  I know it has its own clipboard, but I want to use the MacOS clipboard.  I don't want to "yank" I want to copy/paste.  vim is the only app that blocks this, and it does this by taking over the screen somehow and commandeering the normal selection process.  I don't really understand how it subverts this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH doesn't provide access to the macOS-specific IPC system that 'pbcopy' uses; it only provides the "text terminal" interface, and clipboard access is not typically part of that.

Some terminals do support an operation for copying text into the clipboard (known as 'OSC 52'), but it's not universal – on macOS only iTerm2 has built-in support for that, Terminal.app does not. If you're willing to use iTerm2, take a look at [this blog post](https://jdhao.github.io/2021/01/05/nvim_copy_from_remote_via_osc52/); or if you don't mind compiling extra tools, try [this hack](https://github.com/roy2220/osc52pty) for Terminal.app (it can be used with 'osc52pty ssh' too).

SSH does have the capability to provide access to the X11 graphics interface that Linux tools such as 'xclip' or 'xsel' use, so if you can get XQuartz running on macOS (is that still a thing?), then you should be able to follow any Linux-specific tutorial (e.g. Vim's `"+y` should work if SSH X11 channel is enabled and if you're using a Vim build with X11 support compiled in).

> In the meantime, as a workaround, I'll just use pico, which for some reason easily does what I want with no issues. In fact it's better; I can just select and then copy/paste.

Selecting and copy/pasting does not go through the remote pico or through SSH at all – it is handled by your local Terminal.app. You can do it regardless of the text editor being used.